# How to pass arguments to a task in vscode that executes a snippet linked to a hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have this working hotkey:

```
  {
        "key": "cmd+t",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
            "name": "TryCatch"
        }
    },
```

Which wraps the selected text into a tryCatch block, and adds the wanted logs and error reporting.

However, I want to link it with other sequence of either hotkeys or tasks.

I have this task in `tasks.json`, when when triggered in attempts to perform the above command, it prompts me for user input, because I can't figure out how to pass the name of the snippet as an argument, similar to what is done with hotKey binding configurations in example 1 above.
This is the task:

```
       {
            "label": "insertSnippet",
            "command": "${command:editor.action.insertSnippet}",
            "args": [
                // "${name:TryCatch}",

            ],
        },
```

I've been trying to get tasks to execute without having to wait for user input or pressing `enter` for example, but dreadfully failed. I couldn't find a wait to intercept the execution of a task and pass data or select an item from a menu.

Any help on setting up a single hotKey which then triggers two or more commands?

Please note that I need to commands/tasks in the editor, not in terminal or shell. All the solutions I came across are for shell. Also inputs or text work in shell or in the editor, but not in the dropdown as in the following images, which are triggered by tasks.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

---

Edit, what worked in the end. Thanks a lot @Mark

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
       
        {
            "label": "insertTryCatchSnippet",
            "command": [
                "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
                "${input:tryCatchInput}"
            ]
        },

        {
            "label": "save",
            "command": "${command:workbench.action.files.save}",
        },

        {
            "label": "TryCatch",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "insertTryCatchSnippet",
                "save",
            ],
        },
    ],

    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "tryCatchInput",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
            "args": {
                "name": "TryCatch"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this hotkey shortcut:

```
   {
        "key": "cmd+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "TryCatch"
    },
```

Flawlessly without using macros or extensions. Thanks again.

Comment: tasks run in a Terminal, VSC commands run in an editor window

Comment: That's not very accurate, tasks are not strictly for terminal. I have tasks that average autosave.

Comment: what is `average autosave`? You want to execute VSC command by a task, that is not possible

Comment: "I've been trying to get tasks to execute without having to wait for user input" - I believe this is solved below if you want to use tasks.  "Any help on setting up a single hotKey which then triggers two or more commands?" is a separate question, fo rwhich you could use a macro extension like `Multi-Command`.

Comment: "Also inputs or text work in shell or in the editor, but not in the dropdown as in the following images, which are triggered by tasks."  This can sometimes be done for certain quick inputs but I don't believe for tasks.  If you mean to prepopulate a quick input window with some text when it is opened.

Comment: Which commands do you want to run sequentially?  Have you looked into macros, there are a number of answers here using `Mulit-Command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run vscode commands, like `editor.action.insertSnippet`.  But if they take arguments than I believe you have to use the `inputs` of `tasks.json` to supply the args.  In your `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",

  "tasks": [

    {
      "label": "insertTryCatchSnippet",
      "command": [
        "${input:tryCatchInput}"
      ],
    }
  ],

  "inputs": [
    
    {
      "id": "tryCatchInput",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "name": "tryCatch"
      }
    }
```

where your snippet `name` is defined in some snippets file.

You can then assign this task directly to a keybinding like this (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "alt+w",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "insertTryCatchSnippet",
    "when": "editorFocus"
  }
```

---

If your desired command didn't need any args than you could do something like this in a task:

```
    {
      "label": "SplitTerminal",
      "command": "${command:workbench.action.terminal.split}",
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

You can use multiple vscode commands in a task too (although some commands may need to wait for the previous command to finish and you should make 2+ tasks that then run from a master task with the `dependsOrder` property `sequence`):

```
    {
      "label": "open new terminal and then saveAll",
      // "type": "shell",
      "command": [
        "${command:workbench.action.terminal.new}",
        "${command:workbench.action.files.saveAll}"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Hero, thank you! The secret was in using input and passing the name properly.